# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH with signed certificate in Tomcat

Tags: ssl-certificate-errors, keytool

I have a tomcat server for which I needed a signed certificate. I generated a key using

> keytool -genkey ....

and then generated a CSR and sent it to my company admin.

They gave me back a CER file with the signed certificate and certificate chain.

I installed the root cert, intermediate cert and the signed cert in the keystore using keytool.

But when I use the cert in the server and connect with a browser I am getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error in chrome.

This is what I get when I use openssl to debug.

> $ openssl s_client -connect localhost:18443 -debug -tls1 -msg
>
> CONNECTED(00000003) write to 0x7fecbbc1b4d0 [0x7fecbc019000] (100
>   bytes => 100 (0x64)) 0000 - 16 03 01 00 5f 01 00 00-5b 03 01 5b 1c 08
>   e9 8a   ...._...[..[.... 0010 - 69 73 dd 18 9f 58 98 08-b3 23 dd 76 89
>   3c b8 7b   is...X...#.v.<.{ 0020 - 3e aa ea 61 d8 88 0f eb-af 52 45 00
>   00 2e 00 39   >..a.....RE....9 0030 - 00 38 00 35 00 16 00 13-00 0a 00
>   33 00 32 00 2f   .8.5.......3.2./ 0040 - 00 9a 00 99 00 96 00 05-00 04
>   00 15 00 12 00 09   ................ 0050 - 00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06-00
>   03 00 ff 01 00 00 04   ................ 0060 - 00 23
>   .# 0064 -
>
> > > > TLS 1.0 Handshake [length 005f], ClientHello
> > > >             01 00 00 5b 03 01 5b 1c 08 e9 8a 69 73 dd 18 9f
> > > >             58 98 08 b3 23 dd 76 89 3c b8 7b 3e aa ea 61 d8
> > > >             88 0f eb af 52 45 00 00 2e 00 39 00 38 00 35 00
> > > >             16 00 13 00 0a 00 33 00 32 00 2f 00 9a 00 99 00
> > > >             96 00 05 00 04 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11 00
> > > >             08 00 06 00 03 00 ff 01 00 00 04 00 23 00 00 read from 0x7fecbbc1b4d0 [0x7fecbc014600] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5)) 0000 - 15 03 01
> > > >         00 02                                    ..... read from
> > > >         0x7fecbbc1b4d0 [0x7fecbc014605] (2 bytes => 2 (0x2)) 0000 - 02 28
> > > >         .( <<< TLS 1.0 Alert [length 0002], fatal handshake_failure
> > > >             02 28 24316:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
> > > >         failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL
> > > >         alert number 40 24316:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl
> > > >         handshake
> > > >         failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I have tried all manner of things, from google and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## check if the entry is correct

If you run `keytool --list -keystore <yourkeystore>` then you should get back a `PrivateKeyEntry`, somthing like that:

```
tomcat, Aug 23, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): F2:BA:29:E...
```

## import the certificate

If you have a **signed certificate** and **private key**, then you have to export them to a PKCS12 keystore and import it to a Java keystore. The signed certificate does not work without the key in the keystore.

```
#export to PKCS12, set password -> it has to be the same as the java keystore password in the next step
openssl pkcs12 -export -name tomcat -in cert.cer -inkey key.pem -out tomcat.p12

#import the pkcs12 keystore. make sure, both passwords are the same
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore tomcat.keystore -srckeystore tomcat.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias tomcat
```

## cipher mismatch

Not sure if suitable for your problem, but perhaps will this get you closer to the solution: If there are problems with the certificate, like ERR_SSL_OBSOLETE_CIPHER you could add this in the SSL Connector in server.xml

```
useCipherSuitesOrder="true"
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_SRP_SHA_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_SRP_SHA_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA"
```

Comment: That solved my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer helped me diagnose the cause of my "ssl or cipher mismatch" after I switched from running Tomcat inside the IntelliJ IDE and got it set up for standalone running.

I had set up the keystore for a **URL other than localhost** (myinitials.company.com), but was trying to access it via https://localhost.  As soon as I ran `keytool --list -keystore <yourkeystore>`, it showed that the keystore was set up for myinitials.company.com.  I changed to that host name, and got no more ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.

Hope this helps someone else who finds this page.